# How do I select one row based on similar or opposing data in other rows?

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
id    player_id nat nt_caps
13740   28664   97  24  
13741   28664   68  0   
13742   28664   79  0   
16252   42904   15  40  
16253   42904   68  0   
16254   42904   241 0
```

That's how my table looks. I want to select the player_id's that have either nt_caps = "0" for every nat OR player_id's that have nt_caps != "0" only for nat = "68".

The SQL query I try to use is:

```
SELECT player_id FROM x WHERE nat = '68' AND (nat != '68' AND nt_caps = '0')
```

But then I get player_id '42904' and '28664' because they both have 1 entry that matches the query but I don't want them because they have nt_caps for another nat than nat "68".

I hope you understand what I try to achieve.

Comment: If you want this OR that, why are you using AND?

Comment: To me it sounds confusing. But still as i have understand, change the 1st AND to OR and your query should return ok.

Comment: Are there NULL values in `nt_caps`?

Comment: Please give an example of input and desired output, I understood what you want but it seems many have not.

Comment: I put in nat = 68 and then I want all the player_id's that have either nt_caps = 0 for ALL nat's except for nat = 68 OR player_id's that have nt_caps = 0 for ALL. If they have nt_caps for ANY other than nt = 68 I want to exclude them. The table above is just an example, there's over 40k rows.

Comment: The player_id's above should be excluded since they don't fit my desired output but they're the ones that give me problems.

Comment: @user1207764, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE nt_caps = 0 OR (nt_caps != 0 AND nat = 68)
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. He wants the player to have 0 for ALL the nats (there are multiple records for the same player)

Comment: The problem is that I have more records than the ones showed which have nt_caps = 0 BUT their nat != 68 and then I don't want them (I get them with that query).

Comment: So why don't you add a `GROUP BY player_id`?

Answer (score 1):

First subquery gets rows where all nt_caps equal 0, and the second subquery returns the other rows:

```
(SELECT x1.player_id
FROM x x1
LEFT JOIN x x2
  ON x2.player_id = x1.player_id
  AND x2.nt_caps <> 0
WHERE x1.nt_caps = 0
  AND x2.id IS NULL)
UNION
(SELECT x1.player_id
FROM x x1
LEFT JOIN x x2
  ON x2.player_id = x1.player_id
  AND x2.nt_caps <> 0
  AND x2.nat <> x1.nat
WHERE x1.nat = 68
  AND x1.nt_caps <> 0 // Exclude this line if nt_caps "can be" !=0 instead of "must be"
  AND x2.id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Good comment.  That's how I would have done it.  Keeps it nice and simple and no iteration.